# Doctrine Error "Invalid expression found"

Tags: php, doctrine

I have a table defined by:

```
Modification:
    columns:
        id:
            type: integer
            primary: true
            autoincrement: true
        name: string
        author: string

    attributes:
        export: all
```

When I run this code:

```
$tbl = new Doctrine_Table(
                          'Modifications',
                           Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()
                                             ->getCurrentConnection()
                           );
$tbl->findOneBy('name', 'yacoby');
```

I get this error:

> Doctrine_Table_Exception: Invalid expression found: ()n()a()m()e()
>   /home/yacoby/documents/dev/netbeans/php/Doctrine/Table.php:2741
>   /home/yacoby/documents/dev/netbeans/php/Doctrine/Table.php:1707
>   /home/yacoby/documents/dev/netbeans/ESSearch/test/library/Search/Table/ModsTest.php:21

Does anyone have any idea why and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: which version of Doctrine are you using? The line 2741 corresponds to a comment in the version I have...

Comment: @greg I am using version 1.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the 's' after "Modification"...

If that doesn't have any affect, you may want to check that the table has been constructed properly by calling something like the method `Doctrine_Table::getColumns` and checking the output (i.e. that the array contains the columns you defined).

If it isn't what you expect, check that the files that the models are defined in have been loaded properly.

Comment: Then check the table object you are getting looks perfectly normal : changing this letter should have done something. Try to list the table columns, for instance, using getColumns()

Comment: Does look rather odd, doesn't it. Erm -- @Yacoby, what character encoding are you using for your php file?

Comment: @greg0ire Yeah, it seems that there are no columns associated with the table (getColumns returns an empty array). I need to do more digging.

Comment: BTW, why not use Modification_Table directly?

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was something to do with the tables not loading correctly I think. Bit embarrassed tbh. I have edited your answer, basically paraphrasing the comments so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad you found out! Have fun with Doctrine!

Answer (score 0):

If the table has been set up *already* somehow, the correct way to *get* it is like this:

```
$tbl = Doctrine::getTable($what);
```

I ran into the same error while trying to *construct* (while I should have been *getting*) the `Doctrine_Table` of the `$what` entity to run som magic find functions on it.